# How to put conditions inside angular data binding?

Tags: angular

I am a beginner in Angular 2.I'm trying to display some data using angular. this is my code part

```html
<span> Wages</span><span>{{(Wages|currency:USD$:2)}}</span>
```

above part will display as "Wages $0.00" . Its OK but if there is no value or null in "wages" then it should not display any thing .only need to show 
"Wages"

How can i do that?. I tried some thing below and its not working

```html
<span> Wages</span><span>{{(Wages|currency:USD$:2)||' '}}</span>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can put a condition in your pipe code. If wages == '' then return ''

Comment: You can try using `ngIf` on `span` to totally remove it from DOM.

Comment: Can you post your pipe code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```html
<span> Wages</span><span *ngIf="Wages">{{(Wages|currency:USD$:2)||' '}}</span>
```

This will only render the `<span>` if the `Wages` object has a value

Answer (score 0):

I think this sould have worked ... Try this ?

```
{{(Wages || '') | currency:USD$:2}}
```

By the way, is your `Wages` a string, a number ... ?

Answer (score 0):

if you make a function in your view, then it becomes easier to do logic in your controller

```
{{ mySpecificThing(String1) }}
```

... then in controller define the function to get what you need

Answer (score 0):

you can simply go for ternary operator like

```
{{ Wages !== 0 ? (Wages | currency: USD$: 2) : ' ' }}
```